# Calender System module and webform

Tags: webforms, datetime

Does "Calender System" only works with "content types " ? The date popup options does not show while adding a "date" type field in to a webform node .

- https://drupal.org/project/calendar_systems
- https://drupal.org/project/webform

Date Field properties in a content type .
[image]
Date field properties in a webform node .
[image]

Any clue ?
thanks :)

Comment: Please try to provide links to modules when asking questions. It saves the people who want to help you time.

Comment: for which language type you want use it ?

Comment: i need to use arabic date popup in a webform field .

Answer (score 0):

The module info page at https://drupal.org/project/calendar_systems claims it has webforms support. 4th last item. So I suppose it does not only work for content types.

Comment: Thank you @Neograph734 for your response. Any idea why the date type field is different ? i added the screenshots above

Comment: Sorry, I don't know that.